# How to change Edit Mode in Autodesk Forge Viewer Markup Extension in Typescript?

Tags: typescript, autodesk-forge, autodesk-viewer

I've been trying to implement the Markup Extension in Typescript for Autodesk Forge viewer v6, but it seems like the Typedefinition is missing some of the Namespaces and classes.

I can't use the following line for example:

```
let shape = new Autodesk.Viewing.Markup.EditModeArrow(this.markup);
```

It complains that Markup is not defined.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately the markup extension is not yet covered by our official definitions for Viewer - we will endeavor to address that in the upcoming updates ...

In the meantime as a workaround try declare `Autodesk.Viewing.Markup` as any.

And at run-time make sure both the Viewer core libraries as well as the `MarkupCore` extension is loaded before you call the extension.

Comment: Any timeline for this yet?